# Gradle upload artifacts without changing build.gradle

Tags: gradle

I've got a project from github (Ros-java) which I want to build without modifying. Is it possible to upload artifacts to a Maven (Nexus) repository without modifying the build.gradle for the target projects?

I was looking for a gradle comand line to upload all the artifacts from that project to my own Nexus repository. Ideally, I would like to preserve the dependency information.

Ideas?

Comment: You'd have to write an init script that configures the publishing, and pass it along with `-I`. For more information, see the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).

Comment: That sounds like it might be a solution. I was hoping to avoid reading a 60 chapter manual for a seldom used product.

Comment: You don't need to read the whole manual, but certainly the parts on init scripts and maven publishing.

Comment: Also check out the many samples in the full Gradle distribution.